# Obtener los 10 mejores valores sin repetir ningún elemento de la categoría Cliente

Tags: vba

Lo que me gustaría conseguir es obtener los diez mejores valores para cada cliente en la columna (P) utilizando como parámetro la columna (Q) = NumFab. Luego enliste el número encontrado para Order, Client, y NumbFab en una nueva tabla `=range("B26: B35")`. La restricción es que no puede repetir un cliente después de que se encuentra.

Parte de mi código es como sigue, estoy en un callejón sin salida ahora mismo así que su apoyo es apreciado

```
Sub FindTop10()
 Dim rngDatos As Range
 Dim lNumEntradas As Long
 Dim dOriginal As Variant
 Dim Celda As Range
 Dim RtopTen As Range

    Set rngDatos = h_Calc.Range("o4", h_Calc.Cells(Rows.Count, "x").End(xlUp))

     dOriginal = rngDatos 'Salvar data original

     'apagar notificaciones
     With Application
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
     End With
     'se hay un problema activar notificaciones
     On Error GoTo CleanExit
        With h_Calc
            rngDatos.Sort key1:=Range("x4"), Order1:=xlDescending, 
             Header:=xlGuess
        End With

        ultLinea = h_Calc.Cells(Rows.Count, "o").End(xlUp).Row

        h_Calc.Range("b26:d35").Clear

        Set RtopTen = h_Calc.Range("C26:C35")
    With h_Calc


        i = 4
        For Each Celda In RtopTen

            Do Until Celda.Value = .Cells(i, "P").Value
                Celda.Offset(0, -1) = .Cells(i, "o").Value
                Celda = Format(.Cells(i, "p"), "@")
                Celda.Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(i, "Q").Value
            Loop

        Next Celda

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: y el problema cual seria?

Comment: No estoy seguro de si entiendo la pregunta. Si quieres obtener los 10 mejores valores, ¿no te vale la fórmula de **[K.ESIMO.MAYOR](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/k-esimo-mayor-funci%C3%B3n-k-esimo-mayor-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64)**?

Comment: Hola Patricio, ya lo he intentado pero me da un error al momento de arrastrar los valores, el problema es que un mismo cliente puede tener los diez valores mas alto, pero el requisito es que se tome el valor mas alto de cada cliente que esta en la lista hasta completar diez de ellos

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de como son tus datos? Y también un ejemplo de cómo debería quedar una vez aplicada la macro.